# Radio buttons side by side alternative in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, user-experience

Is there any recommended alternative to the default "Radio Buttons side by side" solution when we need to show a small set of options (2 or 3) to the user?
I mean, we usually do this:

[image]

But I've seen a lot of apps adapting something like "Segmented Controls" from iOS:

[image]

Which I don't think it's a good practice at all.

In my case specifically, I don't think hiding some of the options would be helpful to the user, so Spinners are not a real option. I won't be changing any views either, so it's not like I'm looking for tabs or something like that. And then we have toggle buttons and switches, which I don't think fits my needs, because I won't be switching between states. And finally we have this article that suggests to use simple regular buttons instead: http://kintek.com.au/blog/portkit-ux-metaphor-equivalents-for-ios-and-android/

I'm inclined to use an implementation with regular buttons, like the one in the article, but I wanted to know if there are any elegant alternative to this.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm quite interested in this issue. However, if possible, could you add an image draft to what you think about elegant alternative? (Btw, thanks for the informative link!)

Comment: @AndrewT. To be honest, I don't really know what an elegant alternative would be. All I know is that two radio buttons displayed side by side looks kind of ugly. Of course this is a very subjective matter, but I'm looking forward to discover what other solutions designers came up with. (You're welcome for the link!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are tons of questions posted on UX Stack Exchange on the topic of radio buttons vis a vis segmented controls, and there is one in particular about inserting radio buttons and checkboxes into buttons, but I cant seem to find it at the moment. <s>I also, to the detriment of you and other readers, cannot add images or more than two links to my answer (so ill put them in as plain text) because I don't have enough reputation.</s>Thanks whoever!

I think the main issue with the a segmented control is that, to quote user Pdxd on a UX Stack question : [*Is there any reason to use buttonsets over radio buttons / dropdown pickers?*](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/53953/is-there-any-reason-to-use-buttonsets-over-radio-buttons-dropdown-pickers)

> the con to using button sets is it's difficult to see that you can only select 1 option at a time

I think this is especially true outside of the context of mobile.

I'm personally a big fan of what the product design team over at Dualingo is doing: they've combined a classic horizontal radio buttons and [inserted them into buttons to make the targets large enough for touch-enabled devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qy9e.png). Personally, I think this is the best solution. 
 [image]

jQuery mobile does something similar to this in for their [vertically stacked radio buttons](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/widgets/radiobuttons/), but its worth noting that in the latest releases have moved to using segmented controls for horizontal radios on both [jQuery UI](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/widgets/radiobuttons/) and [jQuery Mobile](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/widgets/radiobuttons/).
[image: jQuery Mobile Vertical Radiobuttons]